# How do I cut out a key line (stroke) around text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I cut out a stroke around text?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click the type and select "Create Outlines"...

[image]

Select the paths you want to delete (the path segment, not the anchor points) with the Direct Selection tool... Hit delete...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your directions, but it still doesn't work. When I click on the path it selects the whole R. I am using the direct selection tool. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The direct selection tool shouldn't select the whole path. You sure you're using that and not the normal selection tool? (You need the white arrow, not the black arrow)

Comment: Hi Cai, yes I am. I don't know why it doesn't work for me. Also, I am on Illustrator CC...does that make a difference?

Comment: @jayjay just before you select the segment to be removed, click on an surely empty place or press Shift+Ctrl+A to deselect all. Otherwise your shape gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to Object -> Expand and it will do the trick for you.

P.S. If your text was not outlined first do right click -> Create Outlines

Just remember that you won't be able to edit text afterwards.

Comment: This only explains how to convert to outlines, but does not answer the question, which was about removing the 2 lines at the base of the 'R'.